# Acer Aspire won't boot properly: power led & batter led come on, fans spin, black screen

Tags: windows-8

I have an Acer aspire V which did:

- During normal usage screen goes black. Fan keeps spinning but can't wake it.
- Power & Battery LEDs still working as expected.
- If you hold the power button everything turns off as expected.
- turning on the laptop: fans slowly spins, no BIOS messages,etc. screen black, LEDs on, etc. Fan(s) spins up but no other action
- The fan(s) change speed too. you can hear them/it slowing down then spinning faster,etc.

OS: windows 8

things I've tried:

- Battery reset with the reset hold in the bottom.
- Holding the power button down for different lengths of time: 10 seconds, 30 seconds.
- Restarting and mashing: <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, etc.
- Allowing battery to run itself down and then plugging it in and restarting.

All without changes. The funny thing is that this happened a couple of weeks ago and then went back to normal. Now I can't get it to do anything.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to an external video source? Could be the monitor going out.

Comment: i haven't. i have to get a HDMI to DIV tomorrow. thanking for replying though.

Comment: @cbrulak What was the result using the external monitor? What happens if you plug in a wired network cable, can you ping the laptop or RDP into it ?

Comment: @Hennes Actually, after I let the battery completely drain out it started up normally. I installed updates and after it restarted did the exact same thing again. Haven't got around to looking at since.